# How to pass parameter to custom function from Linq method?

Tags: c#, linq

How I can pass filterSettnig parameter to CalculateEndDateTime method from Linq ConvertAll method ?

```
public static List<IAppointment> ConvertToIAppointment(
                                 List<Misa.Runtime.Entities.Agenda> appointments,
                                 AgFilterDisplay filterSettnig)
{
    List<Misa.Agenda.IAppointment> result = null;
    if (appointments != null)
        result = appointments.ConvertAll<IAppointment>(CalculateEndDateTime(/*here i want to pass filterSettnig parameter*/));
    return result;
}

private static IAppointment CalculateEndDateTime(Entities.Agenda agenda, 
                                                 AgFilterDisplay filterSettnig)
{
    IAppointment result = null;

    if (agenda.ClusterID > 0)
    {
        if (agenda.StartDateTime.Date != agenda.EndDateTime.Date)
        {
            agenda.EndDateTime = agenda.StartDateTime.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59));
        }
    }

    result = (IAppointment)agenda;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What kind of LINQ are you using? LINQ to SharePoint?

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's a `List`, so that will make it Linq-to-Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select` instead, which is part of LINQ. `ConvertAll` is a `List<T>` method, not a LINQ method.

```
result = appointments.Select(a => CalculateEndDateTime(a, filterSetting))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: will it support to conversion also "result = (IAppointment)agenda;" ?

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta yes, it will return `IAppointment`, which is the return type of the `CalculateEndDateTime` method.